# Is the momentary dipole in between a cell membrane due to the van-der-Waals forces?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, dipole

There are van-der-Waals forces within non-polar molecules. I read it that is mainly due to the instantaneous movements of the electron cloud's distribution. When looking at symmetrical molecules like $\ce{CH4}$, the concept isn't hard to understand. But I have a question regarding the bioelectricity and action potential of human cell membrane.

e.g. Outside the cell membrane the ion concentration is high and inside it's low, thus it creates an instantaneous dipole effect between the cell wall. Can this be due to van-der-Waals forces?

Comment: Looks your rather confused - it's simply difference in charge - basic physics not VdW or sth.